# PHP echo not showing SweetAlert2 pop-up

Tags: javascript, php, echo, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm trying to output a SweetAlert2 message box when a user leaves a username/password input box empty.

```
if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
       {  
           echo '<script language="javascript">';
           echo 'Swal.fire({
                          type: \"error\",
                          title: \"Oops...\",
                          text: \"Please provide login credentials!\"
                          })';
           echo '</script>'; 
       }
```

I've included \ to escape quotes but no message box is appearing at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any output or error in the browser's console?

Comment: Have you put the swal library into html?

Comment: Try to remove \  [https://3v4l.org/WGf34](https://3v4l.org/WGf34)

Comment: _“I've included \ to escape quotes”_ - why? Your _PHP_ string delimiters here are single quotes, so the double quotes don’t need escaping for PHP’s sake. Your actual JavaScript output here reads `type: \"error\",` in those places, and that is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a lot of escaping I normally write larger HTML blocks inside of PHP like this:

```php
<?php
if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"])) {
?>
<script>
    Swal.fire({
        type: "error",
        title: "Oops...",
        text: "Please provide login credentials!"
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Your code is not producing valid JavaScript because the escape `\` is not necessary and therefor will be outputted. The JavaScript engine of your browser does not know what `type: \"error\"` should be and probably you will see an error in your console.

Make sure to include SweetAlert2 BEFORE your code for showing the alert (example for using the CDN):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Maybe you have this include at the bottom of your body but your condition is in the middle of your page?

EDIT: The `language` attribute for the HTML `<script/>` element is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) and should be ommited.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've followed your suggestion however it still isn't showing any pop-up box at all. I have included the jQuery and SweetAlert2 links just before the code and still nothing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is outputted in the browser console (F12 -> console)?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null" is the error coming up

Comment: @AoifeDooley Can you upload your code and share a link please?